# Does axis 2 support REST?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-axis

I am trying to provide REST support in our platform. We already have integrated Axis 2 in our framework. And Axis 2 is supporting the REST. So I was thinking of using Axis 2 itself for providing the REST support.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/rest-ws.html

I also found another blog post on how to create RESTful web service using Axis 2.

http://wso2.org/library/3726

But in the above example, it seems I have to modify the generated WSDL to support REST type of invocation. I have to modify the default WSDL2.0 generated by the axis 2, modify it and pack it again in the aar file and deploy the service. So this time, instead of generating the wsdl, it uses the packaged WSDL and uses this WSDL to create the axis service. This is an issue, that I have to overcome somehow.

But does Axis 2 support all the REST features? I found it has support for specifying the HTTPMethod to be used, the HTTPLocation, InputSerialization, OutputSerialization. Are these sufficient to say that we provide REST support?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As REST is an architectural style, not a specific technology or specification, there is no 'all REST features'. However, you can create RESTful services with Axis 2, and it provides you a lot of features. So you can safely answer the 2nd question with yes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer for your 
question one is : NO, not all feature but a lot 
for question two : YES

to investigate about REST , [Roy Fielding's](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) article will help a lot ,because this is the base of REST concept.

Apart from it , i used [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) for couple of my project as REST stack and it works for me nicely.

But, AXIS2 is also a good choice.